# Finding an Object in an Array List, Defined by a Boolean

Tags: java, boolean, point

I'm working on a project that is supposed to be a maze solver. The code I have is nearly complete, except for one bit. I need to get the index of a point in my array list, but I have a boolean regulating what point I need. I need to be able to get the index of the point that will satisfy the boolean as true, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I've attached some of the code below. I hope it's enough to show you what I mean!

Here's the boolean with the conditions for what the point will be:

```
public static boolean adjacent( Point p1, Point p2 )
{   
    int pointX1 = p1.getX();
    int pointX2 = p2.getX();
    int pointY1 = p1.getY();
    int pointY2 = p2.getY();

    while (pointY1 == pointY2)
    {
        if(pointX1 + 1 == pointX2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(pointX1 - 1 == pointX2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    while (pointX1 == pointX2)
    {
        if(pointY1 + 1 == pointY2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(pointY1 - 1 == pointY2)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Here's what I have so far for my array list:

```
public static boolean isSolvable( ArrayList<Point> points )
{   
    ArrayList<Point> second = new ArrayList<Point>();
    second.add(points.get(0));
    points.remove(0);


    while(second.size() >= 1)
    {

        //if second contains adjacent point. (Add adjacent to array list, and subtract from other array list[point])
        if(points.contains(adjacent(second.get(0), points.get(0))) == true)
        {


        }


    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you have two possible infinite loops in `adjacent(Point, Point)`? Those `while` will run until `X1` and `X2` are different, or `Y1` and `Y2` are different, wich may not occur never, because yo don't change it values.

Comment: Why are you writing a redundant code using different `if`s and returning the same values?

Comment: Yes, I deleted a few lines of codes in order to make this post less lengthy. Should I add them back in for clarification?

Comment: Well, tin the current form it is quite unclear as calls to `adjacent` can never, ever return false. Either it returns true from the first loop iteration of the first while or it is stuck in the while. Perhaps you meant if instead of while? (Sorry if I am wrong with that assumption, but I've seen that a lot with beginners.)  BTW, you can drop the `== true` in the second code block, the call already returns a boolean result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, you have one major problem in your `adjacent(Point, Point)` method. Instead using `while`s (I don't know why you would use them here) change them to `if`s:

```
if(pointY1 == pointY2)
{
    if(pointX1 + 1 == pointX2
        || pointX1 - 1 == pointX2)
        return true;
}

if(pointX1 == pointX2)
{
    if(pointY1 + 1 == pointY2
        || pointY1 - 1 == pointY2)
        return true;
}
```

***EDIT:*** *As @Lars says, you can write this in a one-liner function as:*

```
return Math.abs(p1.getX() - p2.getX()) + Math.abs(p1.getY() - p2.getY()) == 1;
```

Also, I would try a backtracking, a greedy, or even a branch and bound algorithm to solve your maze too.

Comment: Exactly. Or as a 1-liner method: 
`return Math.abs(p1.getX() - p2.getX()) + Math.abs(p1.getY() - p2.getY()) == 1;`

Comment: @Lars That's a great way to express it too!

Comment: Thanks, Shirkam! :)